# Test typescript async function using Jest

Tags: typescript, testing, jestjs

I have the following code in main typescript file:

```
public readonly funcname = async (param: string): Promise<CustomeType> => {
    const constname = somefunction(strparam, jsonparam);
    return Promise.resolve({
        reqname:constname
    });
};
```

This is written under an exported class say exportedservice.

I am writing the following testcase in jest for same:

```
const outputMock = jest.fn(() => {
    return Promise.reject();
});

const exportedserviceobj = new exportedservice();

describe('Statement', () => {
    it('statement', async () => {
        expect.assertions(1);
        const outputResult = await exportedserviceobj.funcname('TestFile');
        outputMock().then(outputResult);
        expect(outputResult).toEqual('undefined');
    });
});
```

while running the test case;  it is throwing a type error:

```
exportedservice.funcname is not a function
```

As I am new to typescript; so after a lot of R&D; I am unable to resolve the issue. Please suggest appropriate way to solve this out. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `exportedservice` defined? if so, did you look at their structure in your test?

Answer (score -1):

You have to mock exportedservice. For example:

```
import * as Exportedservice from './exportedservice'
jest.mock('./exportedservice')
describe('Statement', () => {
it('statement', async () => {
    Exportedserviceobj.funcname = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue('test');
    const outputResult = await Exportedserviceobj.funcname('TestFile');
    expect(outputResult).toEqual('test');
});
```

});